# include toml file from another toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml

I am trying to include a second toml file from `Cargo.toml` file.
I don't known how to do that and i don't known do this is possible.
I am trying this:
`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "toml"
authors = "TANDEX"
version = "0.0.0"
include = ["libs.toml"]
```

`libs.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
termion = "0.9.8"
```

and this:
`Cargo.toml`:

```
include = ["libs.toml"]

[package]
name = "toml"
authors = ["TANDEX"]
version = "0.0.0"
```

`libs.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
termion = "0.9.8"
```

Both of them don't works.
For information I want to automatically generate one file by script and the `Cargo.toml` leave normal.

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem, what are you actually trying to achieve that you think merging toml files would help with? Also [`include`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html) is reasonably well documented and has absolutely nothing to do with what you're trying to do, it specifies files to include when packaging the crate for distribution e.g. asset files to include.

Comment: Also TOML itself does not have support for including other files, see https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/397

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen .toml files explicitly CAN'T be imported into other .toml files. I've read in other forums that doing so would go against the ideals of TOML which is to be simplistic and as minimalist as possible.

I came upon this after searching the web for about 1 hour since I also needed this feature u.u . Sad it's not a part of it.

Also, you could create a script that appends the desired .toml data in your specified file, this would effectively add the contents and you would end up with a single combined file